# How do i open popup window in C# ASP.Net application without Chrome silently blocking it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, popup

I can't use RegisterStartupScript('window.open...), because Chrome blocks the popup without even informing the user.

I can't use "onclientclick=window.open(..." in the markup, because I have to invoke code in the button click event handler before opening the popup window.

I can't expect every user of the website to add the site as an exception in Google Chrome's popup blocker, since they'll assume it's an error on the website and not with the popup blocker.

So what other options do I have?

Comment: If you're not adversed to jQuery, check out the 'jqModal' plugin. Very useful, and its just a hidden div with fancy effects to make it 'look' like a popup, it doesn't actually spawn a new window. So you won't have any browser intervention. And you can put anything you want inside that special div - be it a usercontrol or an iframe to an aspx page of your choice.

Comment: You could use ajax to preform the call to your code and popup the window once that is done..

Answer (score 1):

Although the implementations are different, in general modern browsers will only allow popups in response to a user action, so trying to spawn a window from an ordinary script will be something most browsers will try to prevent.

If there were a workaround for this it would be like turning the clock back about 10 years to popup hell.